# R removing the first and last 5% of elements of a vector

Tags: r, sorting

How can I remove the first and  last 5% of elements of a sorted vector?

Comment: You can check `sample_frac` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, since your vector `x` is already sorted, you can do

```
x[round(0.05 * length(x)) : round(0.95 * length(x))]
```

It does not matter whether `x` is ascending or descending.

Answer (score 4):

Remember vector indices in R start at 1, so you'll want

```
x <- round(0.05*length(v))
v[(x+1) : (length(v)-x)]
```

Comment: Indices in R start at 1. The first element of a vector `v` is `v[1]`, not `v[0]`. So if you want to remove the first element, you want `v[2:length(v)]`, *not* `v[1:length(v)]`.